# Where does flask look for image files?

Tags: python, file-upload, flask, web-development-server

I am setting up a local server using flask. All I want to do currently is display an image using the img tag in the index.html page. But I keep getting **error**

```
GET http://localhost:5000/
ayrton_senna_movie_wallpaper_by_bashgfx-d4cm6x6.jpg 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Where does flask look for files? A Little help would be great.
My HTML code is

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi Lionel Messi</h1>

  <img src= "ayrton_senna_movie_wallpaper_by_bashgfx-d4cm6x6.jpg ">

  </body>

</html>
```

My python code is :

```
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lionel(): 
    return app.send_static_file('index.html')
```

Answer (score 157):

Is the image file `ayrton_senna_movie_wallpaper_by_bashgfx-d4cm6x6.jpg` in your `static` directory? If you move it to your static directory and update your HTML as such:

```
<img src="/static/ayrton_senna_movie_wallpaper_by_bashgfx-d4cm6x6.jpg">
```

It should work.

Also, it is worth noting, there is a better way to structure this.

File structure:

```
app.py
static
   |----ayrton_senna_movie_wallpaper_by_bashgfx-d4cm6x6.jpg
templates
   |----index.html
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def lionel(): 
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

templates/index.html

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hi Lionel Messi</h1>

  <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='ayrton_senna_movie_wallpaper_by_bashgfx-d4cm6x6.jpg')}}" />

  </body>

</html>
```

Doing it this way ensures that you are not hard-coding a URL path for your static assets.

Comment: Is there a way to center the image sourced in this way?

Comment: @frank yes, just center the image as you normally would. Using url_for doesn't change anything here

Comment: I used CSS to center this.  For whatever reason, it wasn't centering in plan HTML.  Sorry, web newb here.  Thanks for the fast reply

Comment: if i use a lot of images, and I store them to the folder name images, can I call the image with 'static' , filename'images/a.jpg'???

Comment: After two days of depression, I found your answer Thanks alot

Answer (score 47):

use absolute path where the image actually exists 
(e.g) '/home/artitra/pictures/filename.jpg'

or create static folder inside your project directory like this

```
| templates
   - static/
         - images/
              - yourimagename.jpg
```

then do this

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')
```

then you can access your image like this in **index.html**

```
src ="/static/images/yourimage.jpg"
```

in img tag

Comment: I was stuck in this issue where I was trying to configure my Apache to serve static images but somehow it was not working. With this solution, I am able to get static images. Thank you

Comment: Do you know whether I can use not only absolute path?

Comment: This works for *every* single file in the directory.

Comment: What's the difference between [`static_folder`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.static_folder) and `url_static_folder`?

Answer (score 10):

From the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#static-files):

> Dynamic web applications also need static files. That’s usually where
>   the CSS and JavaScript files are coming from. Ideally your web server
>   is configured to serve them for you, but during development Flask can
>   do that as well. Just create a folder called `static` in your package or
>   next to your module and it will be available at `/static` on the
>   application.
>
> To generate URLs for static files, use the special `'static'` endpoint
>   name:
>
> ```
> url_for('static', filename='style.css')
> ```
>
> The file has to be stored on the filesystem as `static/style.css`.

Answer (score 9):

It took me a while to figure this out too. `url_for` in Flask looks for endpoints that you specified in the `routes.py` script.

So if you have a decorator in your `routes.py` file like `@blah.route('/folder.subfolder')` then Flask will recognize the command `{{ url_for('folder.subfolder') , filename = "some_image.jpg" }}` . The `'folder.subfolder'` argument sends it to a Flask endpoint it recognizes.

However let us say that you stored your image file, `some_image.jpg`, in your subfolder, BUT did not specify this subfolder as a route endpoint in your flask `routes.py`,  your route decorator looks like `@blah.routes('/folder')`. You then have to ask for your image file this way:
`{{ url_for('folder'), filename = 'subfolder/some_image.jpg' }}`

I.E. you tell Flask to go to the endpoint it knows, "folder", 
  then direct it from there by putting the subdirectory path in the filename argument.

Answer (score 0):

If you harcode src for image in html templates, it will be an app route on flask and the most important thing for image in flask is put it on the static folder

Answer (score 0):

if you have a static folder and inside you have a folder suppose to images and inside in image you type on:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/prettyprinted.png')}}" />
```

you have an address static/images/prettyprinted.png