# How can I add images to Flask?

Tags: python, html, image, flask

I need to add an image to my Flask webpage. And in my index.html file in templates directory there is this tag: `<img src="image.jpg">`

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/image.jpg")
def image():
    return render_template("image.jpg")
```

- it does not work. I wanted an image in my webpage, but in my terminal it says that there is a 404 error with getting the image.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Dharman, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[Where does flask look for image files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207761/where-does-flask-look-for-image-files][) More information can be found here.]

If you wish to render the image in the index.html file, replace the image tag in the index.html file with the following.

```html
<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='image.jpg') }}" />
```

You MUST put the image file in a folder named *static* at which all static files are located. This is vital as it is where the Flask framework finds the required resources at.

When you put

```
@app.route("/image.jpg")
def image():
    return render_template("image.jpg")
```

you are creating a route called **/image.jpg**. When you go to this route, Flask will find a template, which is basically a file that ends with .html inside the *templates* folder. However, a static file like an image cannot be inside the templates folder.