# Image does not integrate with HTML file

Tags: python, html, css, flask

At line 74 I added `static/assets/images/work01-hover.jpg`

[image]

But when I run file Image does not work out. In developer tools, I found out it does not found the image work01-hover.jpg. How to recover this?

[image]

Comment: You can try this. `../static/assets/images/work01-hover.jpg` Also another image file not error?

Comment: still doesn’t work

Comment: I think `work01-hover.jpg`,  `work02-hover.jpg`, `work03-hover.jpg` file `404 NOT FOUND`. Any typos in the source code?

Comment: You can try this. `/static/assets/images/work01-hover.jpg`

Comment: Yes. This works. Should I apply this to templates also?

Comment: Yes, maybe you need. Also you can reference this article [Reference article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207761/where-does-flask-look-for-image-files). This article more useful in your problem situation. If your problem is solved, please check the useful answer.