# display dynamically images using flask

Tags: python, html, flask, web

Suppose I have a camera that captures images in real time and store them in a folder called "./static".

Each processed image should be displayed on a local web page using Flask python. That is, the results will be presented to the system user by displaying each processed image on the web page along with the image’s gps data (which can be clicked to view image location on google maps) .

Any help guys ?? thanks but I am new to Flask

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried the method here ...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207761/where-does-flask-look-for-image-files

Comment: Have you buit the app file, including a route and html file so that they will serve the images?

Comment: Yep. In my main directory I have "maindir/app.py", "maindir/templates/" where I have html files. I also have a "maindir/static/image.jpg"

Answer (score 3):

You need to break down your problem into several, more manageable problems.

- make sure your camera stores the pictures in the correct folder
- create a basic Flask app
- create a view for viewing one image
- extract the GPS data from one image
- create a link to Google Maps for that one image
- create a function which reads the whole directory of images
- either randomly choose a picture, or create an image gallery for all pictures

That is how I would proceed. Each bullet point is one unit of work.

Answering all of them here, ie create a complete application for you, is not the intended scope of StackOverflow.

If you have any more specific questions about a single bullet point, please create a new question.